# Why we put 'a' after each Hindu name?

Tags: sanskrit, name

For example:
Yog becomes Yog'a' or Krishn -> Krishna;
same way Ram -> Rama

Comment: Ram becomes Rama, Krishn becomes Krishna in Sanskrit. But what do you mean by Indian name?

Comment: Yog is incomplete,similarly Yogaa(aa as in umbrella) is also partially correct.Yoga is correct .Some says Shivaa for Shiva but then how will one differentiate between Shiva & Shivaa(Devi).?

Comment: [Devanagari Translation Comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_transliteration#Transliteration_comparison) already discussed on [meta](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/233/277).

Comment: @Pandya The intent of that meta post is what transliterations are allowed on _this_ site. OP here is asking in general why is there a difference in first place when people transliterate on blogs, e-mails, etc.

Comment: We pronounce Raama very incorrectly if we pronounce as- **'Ram'**. Note that **there is A sound(as in 'a'lone) also with M (as in ja'm')**. The **ma** is not **'Maaa'** , it is **Ma** (as in 'mu'mble)

Note that **Rama is not Raaamaaa**. It is Raama, where **Raa is pronounced as in ext'ra'** and **Ma is pronounced as in 'mu'mble.**

So it is better to write Rama as Rama itself. In fact we should write as **Raama**, but fine, Rama is also okay(though, yet, not correct)

Comment: English's 26 letters of its alphabet, are never able to give correct pronunciation to all sound or word. Since each letter has many kinds of sounds, and many sounds do not have letter for them. **Rama**, for instance, **may be pronounced by someone as-** **रमा, रामा, रम, राम, रम्, राम्,** et cetera, as per their **assumptions**. But **only राम is correct pronunciation**. So if you able to read Devanagari, Bengali, Telugu, Tamil, et cetera "**Scripts**", then go with this "**Script**", in place of "**Roman**" "**Script**".

Comment: You have it backwards. Yoga became yog. Rama became Ram. And so forth.

Comment: it depends on what region one is from for e.g. in Tamilnadu most names end with in or im i.e. (Na or Ma) in Karnataka most name ends with aaa karaa and in andhra llu karaa is preferreed.. one insite from sadhguru is A, U, M represent hindu philosophy this three letters indicate hindu philosophy of trinity. A(Brahma or Vayu) karnataka where hanuman and madvacharya are born and madhva religion is followed where Vayu is the  foremost of all the gods. They all belong to latavya devatha. U kara is for Vishnu that is tirupati where lord venkateshwara is worshipped.

Comment: Ma kara is where shiva is worhsipped more.

Comment: Because that is the correct Sanskrit spelling (within the current romanisation scheme) & Hindi is NOT the universal language of Hindus. Case closed.

Answer (score 28):

**TL;DR**: It's due to **[schwa deletion rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa#Hindi)** of Hindi.

---

First off, it is incorrect and incomplete to write the Sanskrit or Devanāgarī word राम (Rāma) as "Rama" as commonly written by English writers on this forum and elsewhere. The table below lists the accepted Romanised transliterations of राम. Same goes for कृष्ण - "Krishna" is not recommended, while Kṛṣṇa or kRSNa is more acceptable.

[IAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration) makes no special use of capital letters so people often capitalize proper nouns, so both rāma and Rāma are valid.

Now for ease of use, people just write 'Rama' or 'Krishna' because it's difficult to type accented letters such as ś, ṛ and even long vowels such as ā (आ) using a [QWERTY keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY). Also, when you just write 'Rama' you are actually transcribing i.e., freely converting sound from one language to another - technically it's not correct as information is lost in the process. A native English speaker might interpret 'Rama' as रम instead of राम.

---

#### Now to your actual question: Why not write राम as Rām instead of Rām**a** & कृष्ण as Kṛṣṇ instead of Kṛṣṇ**a**?

That's because, if transliterated as above it would lead to a different word altogether in Sanskrit. Rām would represent राम् and Kṛṣṇ or kRSN would mean कृष्ण्

Now if you are Hindi speaker, you probably pronounce राम as राम् and vice versa.

But in Sanskrit both are different, म् + अ ([schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa)) = म

So when you are transliterating (especially Sanskrit names and scripture) to Roman alphabet you need to be a little careful, use one of [IAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration), [ITRANS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITRANS) or [Harvard-Kyoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard-Kyoto).

```
+============+=============+================+================+===============+
| Devanāgarī |    IAST     |   ITRANS 5.1   |   ITRANS 5.3   | Harvard-Kyoto |
+============+=============+================+================+===============+
| राम        | Rāma        | raama          | raama          | rAma          |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
| कृष्ण       | Kṛṣṇa       | kR^iShNa       | kR^iShNa or    | kRSNa         |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
|            |             |                | kRRiShNa       |               |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
| योग        | Yoga        | yoga           | yoga           | yoga          |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
| शिव        | Śiva        | shiva          | shiva          | ziva          |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
| महाभारत    | Mahābhārata | mahAbhArata or | mahAbhArata or | mahAbhArata   |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
|            |             | mahaabhaarata  | mahaabhaarata  |               |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
| ज्ञान        | jñāna       | GYaana/GYAna   | GYaana/GYAna   | jJAna         |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
|            |             | j~naana/j~nAna | j~naana/j~nAna |               |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
|            |             | dnyaana/dnyAna | dnyaana/dnyAna |               |
+------------+-------------+----------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Reference: [Learning Sanskrit - Transliterating](http://www.sanskrit-sanscrito.com.ar/en/learning-sanskrit-transliterating-2-1/411)

Comment: Whats the correct pronunciation of "karma" is it "karma" or "kaarma"

Comment: @Xlam pronounced as karma.

Comment: @Xlam From [here](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?script=DI&beginning=0+&tinput=karma+&trans=Translate), कर्म = karma is a noun meaning 'action' whereas कार्म = kārma or kaarma or kArma is an adjective meaning 'active', 'laborious' etc.

Comment: @sv. Truly great explanation. But still I doubt about pronunciation? Why do people say it as Rama while speaking and why not as Ram?

Comment: @AshishSrivastava how many of those '**people**' know about right phonetics and pronunciation rules? People call Raama as Raaamaaaa as they've been listening it that way. And those 'people' are not the founder of pronunciation of the name of Raama. The correct pronunciation is "Raama'', Raa as in ext'ra', and ma as in 'mu'mble. It is the correct pronunciation of word Raama.

Comment: How do I type a letter with a horizontal bar above it? e.g. ā (here I have copied and pasted :) . After searching, found some weird key combinations for Windows. I am on Linux.

Comment: I too copy-paste. There's no easy way. I keep a list of frequently used Sanskrit words in IAST. Wikipedia articles mostly use IAST notation so search & copy also works. To avoid all this hassle some prefer Harvard-Kyoto. @Vineet

Comment: "Now if you are Hindi speaker, you probably pronounce राम as राम् and vice versa." No in Hindi also people pronounce राम  not राम् . The Hindi Grammar says same  म् + अ  equation as you told for Sanskrit. @sv.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Think you are confusing the spelling (राम - Rama) with pronunciation (राम् - Ram) in Hindi? Though we say 'Ram Mandir' in Hindi but write it as राम मंदिर (not राम् मंदिर्).

Comment: I understood why you are getting confused because of the transliteration used for Hindi. Yeah that's misleading I agree. But pronunciation राम  only not राम् . @sv.

Answer (score 9):

**References** for this annswer:

- Chapter 1 of [Samskrita Bharati Pravesha](https://samskritabharati.in/correspondence)
- [Chapter 1](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=qRwJAAAAQAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) of A Practical Grammar of the Sanskrit Language
- Consonants section under **Devanagari transliteration** [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_transliteration#Consonants)

  > The Devanāgarī standalone consonant letters are followed by an implicit shwa (/Ə/). In all of the transliteration systems, that /Ə/ must be represented explicitly using an 'a' or any equivalent of shwa.

---

In DevaNagari languages (such as Sanskrit and Hindi), each *full-form* constant is a combination of *half-form* constant and a vowel.

i.e.

> *full-form* constant = *half-form* constant + vowel

For example,

> म (ma) = म् (m) + अ (a)

Hence, all words have to be ended by a **vowel** but not necessarily by 'a'. For example,

> Vishnu (विष्णु)
>
> Manu (मनु)
>
> Yayati (ययाति)
>
> Draupadi (द्रौपदी)

However, when there is no need of a vowel in **pronunciation** (most of the case if word referers to a **Masculine noun**), then we use 'a'. For example:

> Raama > Rama (राम)
>
> Bhishma (भीष्म)
>
> Drona (द्रोण)
>
> Raavana > Ravana (रावण)
>
> Ganesha (गणेश)
>
> Shiva (शिव) 1
>
> Krishna (कृष्ण) 2

But most of the time, for simplicity we use 'a' instead of 'aa' (for example, we write Aarati (आरती) as Arati) and that should be pronounced (most of the case if word referers to a **Feminine noun**). For example,

> Sitaa -> Sita(सीता)
>
> Shivaa -> Shiva (शिवा) 3
>
> Krishnaa -> Krishna (कृष्णा) 4

---

**Footnotes:**

1 Shiva (शिव) : Masculine noun for one who is auspicious. Example: name of Lord Shiva

3 Shivaa -> Shiva (शिवा) : Feminine noun for one who is auspicious or Feminine noun for one who is consort of Shiva. Example: name of Goddess Parvati

2 Krishna (कृष्ण) : Masculine noun for one whose complexion is dark. Example: name of Lord Krishna, Arjuna

4 Krishnaa -> Krishna (कृष्णा) : Feminine noun for one whose complexion is dark. Example: name of Draupadi

Answer (score 3):

In the Devanagri script (used for Sanskrit) the first alphabet / vowel is 'अ' or 'a'.  If the vowel 'a' is not added to the word, the word is incomplete - Rama without 'a' i.e Ram would be in Devanagri script become 'राम्' and not 'राम'. Similarly for Shiva, Krishna, etc.

The second alphabet / vowel is 'आ' or 'aa'. Whenever 'aa' is added to a word it denotes the feminine. Thus 'कृष्णा' is the name of Draupadi and not Sri Hari 'कृष्ण'.

Hope this clarifies your query.