# Authentication of Mahabharata character names

Tags: mahabharata

Blessings, everyone.  There are so many versions of the Mahabharata with variations on the spellings of character names I.E. Bheeshma, Bhism, Bishma, Bhishma. Is there a reliable location of one list with the most authentic spellings--Closest to the oldest Sankrit translations?   Thank you for your kind consideration.

Comment: You can browse thru the [Puranic Encyclopedia](https://archive.org/details/puranicencyclopa00maniuoft). Also, [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15622/2995) might help.

Comment: Also see: [An Index to the Names in the Mahabharata: With Short Explanations](https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=c1ROAQAAMAAJ)