# Is it "Bhagavad (भगवद्)" -- "GitA/Gitā (गीता)" or "Gita (गीत)"?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, translation-request, sanskrit, gita

As already discussed here: [Why we put 'A' after each Hindu name?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15617/1049), the subsequent "a" in an English transliteration word, is to interpret the Sanskrit word for full pronunciation.

Example:

- RAma (राम) is neither RAmA (रामा) nor RAm (राम्)
- Krushna (कृष्ण) is not KrushnA (कृष्णा)
- Atma (आत्म) is not AtmA (आत्मा)
- ...

Similarly, **Is it "भगवद्गीता" or "भगवद्गीत"?**
<sub>Note: Though in the popular culture including [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavad_Gita), it seems the 1st one, hardly it's spelled with last word as "A" or "ā".</sub>

Comment: [गीता](http://sanskritdictionary.com/g%C4%ABt%C4%81/72299/1)

Comment: You might also be interested in: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109951/sanskrit-language

Comment: if you wanted to know why is गीता and not गीत, i think the answer is that Gita is referred to as Upanishad ( see Gitopanishatsu) at the end of the chapters. Upanishad is a stree-linga word. I think for that reason, instead of गीतम् or गीत,  गीता is used. The heading of the question is what I am answering to and its NOT duplicate if this was your query:)

Answer (score 5):

It is भगवद्गीता, since it is a sacred song. There are other forms (गीत​/गीतम् etc) which mean song / singer and so on but the word गीता in particular means a sacred song.

The Apte dictionary [says](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.2:1:2642.apte):

> गीता gītā
>
> गीता [गै कर्मणि क्त] A name given to certain sacred writings in verse (often in the form of a dialogue) which are devoted to the exposition of particular religious and theosophical doctrines; e. g. शिवगीता, रामगीता, भगवद्गीता.
>
> But the name appears to be especially confined to the last, the Bhagavadgītā;
>
> गीतासुगीता कर्तव्या किमन्यैः शास्त्रविस्तरैः । या स्वयं पद्मनाभस्य मुखपद्माद्विनिःसृता ॥
>
> quoted by Śrīdharasvāmin.

Note that आत्मा is the correct version since it's root is आत्मन् (नकारान्त पुल्लिङ्ग).

Also note that the English transliteration people use in this site is only halfway there: they should be spelling गीता as 'g**I**tA' but rarely does anyone do it (nArAyaNIyam for example). They seem to only care for the आ and nothing else.