# Why is the Gita called "GitA" instead of 'Gitah' or 'Gitam'?

Tags: sanskrit, gita

GitA (in sanskrit language) is a feminine-gender-word. My question is : Why, instead of named 'Gitah'(masculine Gender) or Gitam (neuter gender), it is named GitA? Puranas are called 'PURANAM' by the way.

Also, Why is it called a **song** instead of Upadesha?

I am interested in the scriptural or grammatical basis and NOT 
opinions.Thanks.

**Please note that this question is not duplicate as I am asking the reason behind the name.**

Comment: Maybe this will answer your question: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20239/is-it-bhagavad-%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D-gita-git%C4%81-%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BE-or-gita-%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%A4/20249#20249

Comment: @user1952500 no logic is provided there!

Comment: Ah yes, very true. It will be useful to clarify the question a bit so that it doesn't attract similar answers.

Comment: @user1952500 you could edit if you like

Comment: You can add the "Sanskrit" tag ..@Partha

Comment: I don't think there is a reasoning behind gender in Sanskrit for many cases. For example कथा and गाथा are feminine and refer to story and poetry/songs.

Comment: @user1952500 thats fine but Ramayana Mahabharata and purana all end with m while a part of Mahabharat with A.Further, why song?

Comment: (There may be individual rules and I'm guessing here) The ayanam (neuter) is used in the Ramayanam. Many of the Natakas are neuters and hence we see the 'abhijnana shaakuntalam' etc. I think the Ramayana and Mahabharata are neuters because they are mahakavyas (kavyam is neuter) EDIT: This is not true as kaadambarI is a feminine word though it is a gadya (masculine)

Comment: First good observation according to bannanje Govindacharya this means this grantha is specifically meant for Female and general public those who are not eligible to read vedas.. Vedavyas does one thing also is for specific purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

After giving some thought, the answer that came to my mind is :

1. It is in **feminine** form (GitA) because it when separated from the Mahabharata is treated as an Upanishad and '**Upanishad' is a feminine word in Sanskrit**. So each chapter of Gita ends with saying 'GitAsu Upanisatsu..'
2. According to the sanskritdictionary.com, gita means '**chanted**' also, alongwith 'song' and hence the slokas primarily chanted by Sri Krishna are known as Srimad-Bhagavad-GitA.