# Which is correct name Krushna or Krishna?

Tags: krishna, name

I have listen from one of the preist after some discussion about god and he suggested me to say as krushna instead of Krishna. I wondered and said that both are same. But he insisted and I was treated as lesser known about the name. And added that chanting the name as Krishna doesn't have any effects and of no use. If someone is chanting the name Krushna, he gets immediate effects and realise the god.

I am totally confused between these two names as many of our villagers confused hearing Krishna.

Which is correct or both of them?

**Any scriptures tells about the correct name?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why we put 'A' after each Hindu name?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15617/why-we-put-a-after-each-hindu-name)

Comment: You should pronounce it Krishna as in Cream say.

Comment: If Krishna is to be pronounced as "Krushna" then Vrisha (bull) has to be pronounced as Vrusha, Hridaya (heart) as Hrudaya and so on.

Comment: Correct pronunciation is "Krushna". And "Krishna" is it's *apabhramsha* (distortion).

Comment: कृष्ण is the right word..people write it in different ways in English..and this is explained in answers of the question which i hv linked as a duplicate..however now i think @Rickross has clarified the doubt here..in devanagri languages the word remains same for reading/writing/pronouncing.. but in English writing, devanagri words change a lot.. for example, Riksha can be written as Riksh or Ruksh or Ruksha but it should be pronounced from devanagri only as mentioned in the screenshot here https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgIG5.png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### The correct name is **कृष्ण** with ण.

(IAST Kṛṣṇa)

The problem in pronunciation is due to the mistake in transliteration from Sanskrit to English. Now a days, the letter 'ऋ' is written as  'ri' and pronounced as 'रि' which is wrong. Same applies to ऋग्वेद which is now written as Rig Veda. Its transliteration according to IAST is Ṛgveda. Same for 'ऋषि' whose transliteration is Ṛṣi according to IAST.

To overcome this problem, [different transliteration schemes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_transliteration) like [ITRANS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITRANS) , [IAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration), [Harward Kyoto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvard-Kyoto) have been designed. Using one of those transliteration schemes would solve the problem.  (IAST has an advantage over other as capital letters are also allowed in it. Other transliteration schemes don't have capital letters. Using capital letters is wrong transliteration according to other schemes.)

---

It is written as कृष्ण  in all the scriptures.

> इन्द्रस् तदात्मनः पूजां विज्ञाय विहतां नृप
>   गोपेभ्यः **कृष्ण**नाथेभ्यो नन्दादिभ्यश् चुकोप ह
>
> Indras tadātmanaḥ pūjāṁ vijñāya vihatāṁ nṛpa
>   gopebhyaḥ **kṛṣṇa**-nāthebhyo nandādibhyaś cukopa ha
>
> Śukadeva Gosvāmī said: My dear King Parīkṣit, when Indra understood that his sacrifice had been put aside, he became furious with Nanda Mahārāja and the other cowherd men, who were accepting Kṛṣṇa as their Lord.